# Polymer does not show anything on http server

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have created a Polymer element as follows.

hello-world.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

 <dom-module id="hello-world">

    <template>
        <p><h1>Hello World</h1></p>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer ({ is: "hello-world", }); 
    </script>

 </dom-module>
```

The html file that loads it is as follows:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="elements/hello-world.html">
    </head>

    <body>
        <hello-world></hello-world>
    </body>
</html>
```

In command prompt, I am present in the folder (C:\Users\Admin\polymer) that contains index.html and I have installed a http-server in the folder and have started a server with

```
http-server C:\Users\Admin\polymer
```

Launching localhost:8080/index.html shows a blank webpage. Where is the problem that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You said your html file is `hello-world.html`. But you are trying to access `localhost:8080/index.html`. See the difference? Access either`localhost:8080/hello-world.html` or rename `hello-world.html` to `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I, however, mentioned that the polymer element is written in 'hello-world.html'. And 'index.html' is accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the URL I was typing in the address bar. I must have typed "localhost:8080/polymer/" where polymer is the folder that contains index.html.

I was instead typing 'localhost:8080/index.html', which was wrong. The answer by Rando helped me to figure this out. Thanks Rando!